# jsp include vs jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a jsp page that has separate modules or widgets on it. To improve the overall load-time of the page, I was thinking of fetching those independent modules in parallel.
I have 2 strategies :

**1: JQUERY AJAX**

```
function getSimilars(){
    $('#similars').load('getSimilars.jsp');
}
function getActivity(){
    $('#activity').load('getActivity.jsp');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var funcList = ['getSimilars','getActivity'];
        $.each(funcList, function(i,v){
            window[v]();
    })
});
```

**2: STATIC INCLUDE**

```
<div id="similars">
    <%@include file="getSimilars.jsp" %>
</div>
<div id="activity">
    <%@include file="getActivity.jsp" %>
</div>
```

I know that **1** runs from the browser while **2** runs during compile time. But which of these would make my page load faster?

**EDIT:**
While the jquery method runs both function in **parallel**, I think the 2nd method makes those 2 `include`s run **serially**. Am I right ?

Comment: Measure and compare. It's the only way to know for sure.

Comment: I see. But is there something best-practices wise that puts one over the other?

Comment: The first will obviously trigger the dom ready event faster because it retrieves the content later. Whether or or not it appears to be faster is a completely different question though and depends on what these includes contain in relation to the rest of your page.

Comment: For your edit: the jQuery way will load them in parallel, however it does it after your server sends the content, resulting in 3 separate http requests. Method 2 will result in the server compiling everything before returning it to the browser in 1 http request.

Comment: If you measure it, more than likely method 2 will result in all of the content appearing faster, however, to the user, your page will probably appear to be faster using method 1 because the rest of the page will appear while the additional content is being requested.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This makes my choice easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1>**
Loading page via ajax will make load the partial page loading faster, but the rest of the 2 pages load time will vary every time during page call and those will depend on network bandwidth.

**Option 2>**
We know from Java EE Specification, that all jsp pages are compiled first time as servlet and then no further compilation are needed and the generated .class file executes directly in all later calls to the page.

So there will not be any further time dependency here for page loading.

Now if the application needs the full page at same time the **Option 2** should be chosen.

Where as

if the application page loading with lazy loading experience can be used for better user experience then the **Option 1** should be chosen.

Comment: Thanks Piyas, this makes sense. I prefer the Jquery-way because the two widgets are independent and can be loaded later. But you have got option 1 and 2 mixed up in your answer. Please correct.